# .scroll() works on codepen but doesn't in my Electron Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, electron

The `scrollToTop` method works in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRWmYa), but when I use it in my app (uses single file components) it throws these 2 errors when I hit the button with `@click="scrollToTop"`:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: this.$refs.scrollContainer.scroll is not a function"

TypeError: this.$refs.scrollContainer.scroll is not a function
```

---

#### UPDATE

Can someone reproduce it? I've created a new project from [this boilerplate](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/electron) and I get the same result there

```
# Install vue-cli and scaffold boilerplate
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init vuetifyjs/electron my-project

# Install dependencies and run your app
cd my-project
yarn # or npm install
yarn run dev # or npm run dev
```

Could someone try to reproduce it by creating a test project and add the following code into the **App.vue**:

1) add this CSS

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.scrollContainer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

2) This method:

```
methods: {
  scrollToTop () {
      console.log(this.$refs.scrollContainer)

      return this.$refs.scrollContainer.scroll ({
        top: 0, 
        behavior: 'smooth' 
      })
  }
}
```

3) This div around the v-container:

```
<div class="scrollContainer" ref="scrollContainer">

</div>
```

4) and the button:

```
<v-btn fab 
       dark 
       fixed bottom right 
       @click="scrollToTop"  ref="button">
  <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

---

P.S.

When I added `console.log(this.$refs.scrollContainer)` into the `scrollToTop` function I get the element in the console:

[image]

Comment: I was getting `Property or method "onScroll" is not defined` using your codepen. When I removed the onScroll attribute everything seems to work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvKRGx

Comment: Can you verify that this.$refs.scrollContainer is your DOMElement and not null?

Comment: @sklingler93 sorry, I forgot to remove `onScroll` from there, it's not related to the issue, it works with and without it

Comment: @Un1 I'm not seeing the error though

Comment: @sklingler93 yeah, that's the problem it totally works in the codepen, the problem is the same code doesn't work in my app, so I cannot figure out why

Comment: @Borjante how do check is it's not null? I updated the question, I added that console.log in there and it returns the div in the console

Comment: That means its not null.. From the top of my head thought, I remember scroll() was a method from the window object, not DOMElements

Comment: @yuriy636 sure, I just updated the question and added steps to reproduce, could you please check it out and see what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electron 1.8.2 [is based on Chrome 59.0.3071.115](https://electronjs.org/releases#1.8.1), which has [partial support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior) of the relatively new ["Scroll Behavior"](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-window-interface) specification (which includes the `Element.scroll()` method you are using).

Meanwhile you can use the [smooth scroll polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll):

```
npm install smoothscroll-polyfill
```

And in App.vue:

```
require('smoothscroll-polyfill').polyfill();
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that works! Thank you very much for the explanation and the ready to use lines of code, that's perfect!